# Laravel Spatie Permission for Multi Tenant

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant, laravel-permission

Laravel version:7.16, Spatie/laravel-permission version:3.13

I am creating kind of multi tenant application.

All tables will have company_id.

users table also gets company_id.

I followed these links.

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/issues/280#issuecomment-318693324

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/issues/280#issuecomment-322216146

I added company_id to model_has_roles and model_has_permissions tables.
And made global companyTenant trait and used it for

But middleware didn't work.

How can I customize this fully?
I think I need to customize `HasRoles` trait but I don't know how I can do it.
When I debug `auth()->user()->roles` it didn't show roles which a user had.
I inserted value in `model_has_roles table`

```
companyid: 1,
role_id:1,
model_type: 'App\User',
model_id: 1
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you!